# addEventListener not working for multiple links

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, and am having trouble making a click event handler working on multiple links. My code is given below:

```
<body>
    <ul id="test">
        <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

and the JS code:

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

The event works fine for the "First" link, but not for the second. Any ideas where I am going wrong.  [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/epqamd06/2/)

Comment: querySelector returns the first element you need to use querySelectorAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this for the JS:

```js
var links = document.getElementById("test");

links.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

```html
<body>
<ul id="test">
<li><a href="#">First</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the simplest solution.

Comment: @user2994590 This will alert if you click in the list outside the links.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `querySelectorAll()` to select every `a` and then use `for` loop because it returns `NodeList`

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello world");
  });
}
```

```html
<ul id="test">
  <li><a href="#">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Method **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)** only select single element,  instead use **[`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** and bind click event handler using iterator.

```js
// convert NodeList to Array and then iterate using forEach method
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).forEach(function(ele) {
  ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Hello world");
  })
});
```

```html
<body>
  <ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#">First</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelectorAll in place of querySelector and which will return an array and loop it through in foreach and add event listener to all.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
Array.from(links).forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
   })
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, you need to convert the return value of `querySelectorAll` to an Array before you can call Array methods on it.